# Viewing Thumbnails Over USB (MTP)

Tags: usb, android, mtp, thumbnails

When managing files on an Android device over USB (MTP), and in particular photos & videos, it's essential to be able to see thumbnails.  They appear painlessly & automatically on Windows, but after many hours of failed attempts, I cannot seem to find any working solution on Linux.  I'm using Kubuntu 20.04.  What I've tried:

- Dolphin 19: MTP thumbnails do not work properly (as reported in this bug: https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=419887)
- Nautilus: Fails to access the MTP device at all (it shows: *Unable to open MTP device "001,022"*). I've spent several hours looking for solutions to this, but to no avail. Note that I'm unsure if thumbnails would work even if MTP itself were able to work (I suspect it might be broken there too, per [this issue](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/-/issues/336))
- Thunar: Fails to access the MTP device but shows no error (the device is listed when I plug it in, but selecting it shows no files).
- gMTP: Always shows "no device attached"
- PTP is not an option, as it doesn't allow access to the true filesystem (photos appear in many places on the Android device, depending on the app from which they originated - so it is necessary to actually navigate file structure itself)
- WiFi is not an option, as it's not possible while traveling (i.e. on buses & planes).  Simple USB is the goal.

Ultimately, Dolphin seems to be the only thing that can browse the device at all - and it shows no thumbnails.  So far, I've just been rebooting to Windows every time I need to manage data on my phone - but it really doesn't seem like that should be necessary for something so basic.  Any insight as to how I can get thumbnails to work properly when browsing MTP would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: same behavior in Lubuntu 20.04.